# How to add characters into string

Tags: php, string

I have a string

```
$str = "a,b,c,d,e";
```

And I want convert string as:

```
$str_convert = "'a','b','c','d','e'";
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my solution:

```
<?php
$str = "a,b,c,d,e";
$arr = explode(',',$str);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = "'$value'";
}

$str_convert= implode(',', $arr);
echo $str_convert;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$str = "a,b,c,d,e";
$items = split(",", $str);
$convert_str = "";
foreach ($items as $item) {
   $convert_str .= "'$item',";
}
$convert_str = rtrim($convert_str, ",");
print($convert_str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a different solution using functional programming coding style, here it is:

```
<?php
$str = 'a,b,c,d,e';

$add_quotes = function($str, $func) {
    return implode(',', array_map($func, explode(',', $str)));
};


print $add_quotes(
    $str,
    function ($a) {
        return "'$a'";
    }
);
```